# Why can't I force the height of my FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, resize, scrollview, android-framelayout

I'm setting my FrameLayout's height to 400, but it remains 64.

frame_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</FrameLayout>
```

MyClass.java

```
container = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_layout, scrollFrame, false);
scrollFrame.addView(container);
container.setLayoutParams(new 
    ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400));
Log.d("Output", "FrameLayout Height: " + container.getHeight());
```

Output

```
FrameLayout Height: 64
```

Even if I set the layout_height="400" in the xml, it still is 64. I think this has something to do with ScrollViews. (I cannot use LinearLayouts though, as they create a slew of other problems to my code.) I want the FrameLayout to dynamically resize based on the views I place in it. (A LinearLayout does resize automatically, yet it resizes to a height 10x what I am trying to display, making the ScrollView far too big; then there's a positioning issue because the LinearLayout tries to force positions on views I am trying to arrange manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while I can't answer exactly as to why a FrameLayout can't be given a specific size, I'd assume it has something to do with the design of the FrameLayout. What I was trying to do was ultimately an abuse of the UI and a poor programming design approach to my app. So if you think you need to manually resize FrameLayout, ask yourself if it's really necessary - there might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

try using weightSums and layout weights. Here is a layout with two frames that are always 50% of the screen, regardless what gets put inside of them and their height.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          tools:context="com.nimbits.android.HomeActivity"
          android:weightSum="1.0">




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@id/main_frame"
        android:layout_weight=".5">


    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@id/data_frame"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false">


    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well I was actually trying to set the Frame width to a specific size, not a weighted ratio. I ended up just using a RelativeLayout as a simple, resizable frame (and not taking advantage of its features). I ultimately scrapped the approach entirely. I should answer my own question I suppose.